# Wordpress: WP_Query ordering anomaly

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm ordering a set of posts by an ACF date field using these arguments in `WP_Query`

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_key'      => 'date', //ACF date field
```

Which seems to work, except it's throwing an anomaly.

This is an echo of the list of dates (stored as `Ymd`)

```
20211221
20220118
20220125
20220201
20220208
20220215
20220222
20220301
...
20221122
20221129
20221206
20221213
20221220
20220111
```

The last one, which should be second, is appearing last. (they are weekly dates starting 21st December 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `meta_value_date` instead of `meta_value` as `orderby` parameter.

see also https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Comment: The interesting thing is that, at the root of the issue, the values stored in the database are currently `Ymd` but, at some time had been stored as `Y-m-d` but your answer is correct  as I haven't changed the stored format.